# Shirk in your mind through waswas count as shirk?

Tags: shirk

Shirk is commited when one believes in someone other than Allah mainly. But if a Muslim says a shirk statement in his mind due to waswas, is it shirk even though he repents and doesnt believe in anyone or anything other than Allah? It is also hard for me to control waswas sometimes